# Is it safe to install plumbing fittings with a battery powered impact wrench?

Tags: plumbing, tools, powertools, fastener, hand-tools

I'm using [Uponor brass fittings](https://www.uponor.com/en-us/s/propex-lf-brass-male-threaded-adapter-3-4-pex-x-3-4-npt-lf4527575) to connect to old galvanized Pipe. Some of these fittings are *very* hard to get to because they're near the eve of the house -- maybe even impossible. I'm wondering if it's safe to zip these fittings on with an impact wrench.

The spec sheet for these fittings are very specific, defining all elements.

[image: Diagram of fitting]

For the 3/4 Uponor fitting, `F` (which looks like `r`) is 1.06 inches so I would need a 28 mm socket. My impact wrench can put out 300 ft/lb of fastening torque. Is it ok to zip these on to galvanized pipe with a little bit of pipe dope, or should I use a monkey wrench like it's 1840?

Comment: I wouldn't use a powered wrench. If you're thinking about using an impact wench, though, I presume you have a socket which fits; you could drive that by hand with a rachet wrench or T-handle or whatever...

Comment: You can use impact wrench to unscrew, but would not use it to screw on

Comment: @keshlam It would still be _really_ hard. It's a gabled roof with probably a 40 deg incline. The pipes run on the other side of the top plate. I also don't think god himself could torque 50 lbs with a T-handle. (or a ratchet when you can't put your weight behind it).

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how an impact wrench would improve matters...

Comment: Because my arm extended with an impact wrench could reach the fitting and I can use the same ceiling joist that would stop me from getting to it with a ratchet to hold the impact wrench while fastening.

Comment: Torque sticks to limit your wrench’s enthusiasm, maybe?

Comment: Use an impact to get it on (don't let it hammer more than once, if at all), use a ratchet to torque to final condition.

Comment: With pipes it is important to use two wrenches, one to hold the pipe and the second to turn the fitting.  Impact wrenches do not let you feel the final turn, so very easy to tighten too much and ruin the fitting and/or pipe.

Comment: Seems like a photo of the installation area would be very helpful to clarify the situation you're dealing with.